# MultiLevel indexing pandas trying to collate two different Series

Tags: python, pandas

So currently I am trying to write a function which will take a given document id, and produce a list of other document ids related to this. This is to be achieved by checking this document id against a table with document id's and user id's, each user id then gets checked for what document id's they have accessed.

I have a function which will return a pandas Series for either of these requests, but now I would like to put them together so I can run calculations.

I believe the best way to go about this is to utilise MultiLevel indexing, producing a DataFrame like this:

```
user_id     document_id
user_a      doc_a
            doc_b
            doc_c
user_b      doc_d
            doc_e
user_c      doc_f
            doc_g
```

I am not sure how to go about producing this though. What I can do currently is produce a Series of user_id, I then make a DataFrame with this Series as the first column. I can then produce a second column like so:

```
df['document_id'] = df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: return_documents(x))
```

However, all this is doing is producing a series in each cell of the document_id column.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what u need is [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['document_id'] = df['user_id'].apply(lambda x: return_documents(x))

df = df.explode('document_id')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, for some reason I needed to add .tolist() at the end of .apply part, but its all working now, thanks a lot!